# Document.get on nested document returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I use Document.get on a nested document it returns undefined, where as when I use Document.get with the full path it works

Example:

```js
const PostsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        name: String
    }
});

const Posts = mongoose.model('posts', PostsSchema);

const doc = new Posts({
    author: {
        name: 'Harry'
    }
});

console.log(doc.get('author.name'));
// "Harry"
console.log(doc.author.get('name'));
// undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the difference between the two ways you've presented is related to the difference between Subdocuments and nested paths as explained in the official doc: [Subdocuments versus Nested Paths](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments-versus-nested-paths)

Comparing to the examples given, 'author' is not a Subdocuments of the 'Posts', it's a property defined in the Schema, therefore, the correct syntax, as presented in the official doc [Document.prototype.get()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-get), is to pass the path as a string (as the first way you typed):

```
doc.get(path,[type],[options])
```

> - path «String»
> - [type] «Schema|String|Number|Buffer|*» optionally specify a type for on-the-fly attributes
> - [options] «Object»
> - [options.virtuals=false] «Boolean» Apply virtuals before getting this path
> - [options.getters=true] «Boolean» If false, skip applying getters and just get the raw value

Comment: If I understand what your saying, you can not use nested documents as normal documents?

Comment: I don't think so, since the other syntax (with dots) refer to documents and subdocuments. But one interesting way to use subdocuments instead of simple nested properties ( given the right cases) is to find the subdocument by it's _id, since this property is created for each document.

Comment: In what cases would that be useful?

Comment: To be honest I haven't worked with much levels of documents, but I suppose if you want some level of relational (even mongoDB being a NoSQL) between documents you could use one schema as a subdocument. I also don't know much about the advantages or disadvantages of this aproach but I know it's possible.